# Как в backbon использовать методы типа /#show

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Изучаю backbone, сделал приложение, которое отображает некую коллекцию. Сделал функционал для отображения одного экземпляра из коллекции. 
Что делаю сейчас вручную:

1) загружаю localhost:3000

2) дописываю в url /#show/5

3) получается localhost:3000/#show/5

4) enter и там где положено вижу данные одного экземпляра, страница не перезагружается

Как это же повторить в коде, чтобы нажать на элементе левой кнопкой мыши и получит то же поведение?
Я пытался добавить ссылку /#show/5 и что то делать с этим, но либо ничего не происходит, либо перезагружается страница.

Comment: может не совсем по теме, но.. какой ещё бэкбоун в 2018-м то году

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko , Это было нужно для тестового задания при приеме на работу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отвечу сам:

В моем случае не там вешал обработчик click.
У меня получилось так:

```
$('.show_link').click (event) ->
      event.preventDefault()
      Backbone.history.navigate $(this).attr('href'), {trigger: true}
```